# /usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes: which is used?

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

I'm using: Ubuntu 14.04.3 (64 bit). In my `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes` directory, there are about 15 different keyboard mappings (e.g. ibm, xfree 86, etc.), along with a README and an "aliases" file.

Is there a mechanism (a command or utility) that will tell me which of these is currently in use? I'm attempting to remap the "Omni" key on my old Northgate Omnikey Ultra keyboard (still the best I've used over the past 20 years or so) to serve as a "Windows"/"Super"/"Penguin" key, and from everything I've read, one of these files would be the place to start.

I can see the key functioning with the `xev` utility, but have been completely unsuccessful in being able to remap it over the years, and am determined to give it another shot.

Thanks in advance for any help ...

Answer (score 5):

I can't take credit for this answer: it's [someone's answer to your same question on another forum](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/usr-share-x11-xkb-keycodes-which-is-used-4175579518/#post5544044), but I'm posting the answer here because it helped me, and askubuntu was the first place I looked.

`$ setxkbmap -print -verbose 10` tells you things about your xkb setup.

The output includes which keycodes are in use by your hardware. In fact there may be more than one in use: partial sets of codes from different files are concatenated, and expressed in the output using a `+` sign.